# How can I fill NA-values in a data frame column based on the values from an other column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to fill the NA-values in F2-column, based on the the most common F2-value when grouped by F1-column.

```
  F1 F2
1 A  C
2 B  D
3 A  NA
4 A  C
5 B  NA
```

Desired outcome:

```
  F1 F2
1 A  C
2 B  D
3 A  C
4 A  C
5 B  D
```

Thank you for help

Comment: @Leero11 what value should be inserted when there are ties?

Comment: @markus in a tie situation either one is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution. First define a function for Mode (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/5635580)) and then apply it to you data frame, i.e.

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

df$F2 <- with(df, ave(F2, F1, FUN = function(i) replace(i, is.na(i), Mode(i))))

df
#  F1 F2
#1  A  C
#2  B  D
#3  A  C
#4  A  C
#5  B  D
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(F1) %>%
  mutate(F2 = replace(F2, is.na(F2), 
                      names(sort(table(F2), decreasing = TRUE)[1])))

#  F1    F2   
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 A     C    
#2 B     D    
#3 A     C    
#4 A     C    
#5 B     D
```

In case of ties, preference is given to lexicographic order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First in `df2` I get max count by the variable `F1` where F2 is not missing. That will give you the most common F2 value when groups by F1. I join it back onto the original data.frame and use a `mutate` to fill by the new variable `F2_fill` and then remove it from this variable from the data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~F1, ~F2,
 'A',  'C',
 'B' , 'D',
 'A'  ,NA,
 'A',  'C',
 'B',  NA)

df2 <- df %>% 
        group_by(F1) %>% 
        count(F2) %>% 
        filter(!is.na(F2), n == max(n)) %>% 
        select(-n) %>% 
        rename(F2_fill = F2)

df3 <- left_join(df,df2, by="F1") %>% 
      mutate(F2 = ifelse(is.na(F2), F2_fill,F2)) %>% 
        select(-F2_fill)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave` with `table` and `which.max` and subsetting with `is.na` when it is a `character`.

```
i <- is.na(x$F2)
x$F2[i] <- ave(x$F2, x$F1, FUN=function(y) names(which.max(table(y))))[i]
x
#  F1 F2
#1  A  C
#2  B  D
#3  A  C
#4  A  C
#5  B  D
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(F1 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B")
  , F2 = c("C", "D", NA, "C", NA))
```